# Gensim Word2vec, how works parameter "shrink_windows"= true in cbow style?

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I saw here https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html that the class Word2Vec has a parameter named shrink_windows and i'm trying to understand how it works for CBOW architecture. What does specifically? Does use padding to make sure you have final contexts of the same length?

Answer (score 1):

No padding is ever used. Context windows are always limited by the number of available words in the text you provided. (So, for the 1st word in a text, there will be no context-words from 'before' it. For the last word, there will be no context words from 'after' it.)

The `shrink_windows=True` setting is the default, and matches the behavior of the original Google-released `word2vec.c` code, & other related implementations of related algorithms - including, last I looked, Facebook's FastText.

For any given center target word being considered for training predictions, rather than using the full `window` the user specified, these implementations (and Gensim with `shrink_windows=True`) pick some other random window-size up to the configured `window`.

So when your model is configured `window=5, shrink_windows=True`, the actual tight training loops are using windows in size from 1 to 5. *This is how most word2vec implementations have worked since the unveiling of the algorithm*, and the intent of this behavior is to weight nearer-words more, in a way that's speedy to apply. (By dropping some of the farther words, some of the time, training is sped up. If instead the farther words' influence were decreased by some factor, that would require *extra* calculations, slowing the training down.)

In general, this default is probably the right thing for true natural-language-sourced training text, where proximity is a strong signal of word-relatedness.

On the other hand, some word2vec corpora are not real language, but word-like groupings of tokens - and the fact two 'words' are next-to each other is an arbitrary result of some data-extraction choice. In such a case, you might not want to weight closer-neighbors' influence more. That's when `shrink_windows=False` may be worth trying.

(In such cases, you may also want to take a look at the Gensim parameter `ns_exponent`, which allows you to vary another parameter that was fixed at `0.75` in early word2vec-implementations. The academic paper linked from the `ns_exponent` parameter documentation describes more what situations might benefit from a non-default value, and other values to try.)

Comment: I am implementing CBOW in pytorch and would like to have this functionality. A batch is composed by 32 sentences of my corpus but if I use a random window size between 1 and 5 for each sentence of the batch I will have contexts of equal length but different between each sentence of the batch. I have a list of contexts that have different lengths and I can't transform them into a tensor in the collate function of the dataReader

Comment: If you're having a problem implementing something in `pytorch`, that may warrant a separate specific question to `pytorch` experts, or studying an existing `pytorch` CBOW implementation for ideas. (One must exist already, right?) But note that in Gensim & othr word2vec implementations, the randomly-smaller effective windows (in a variable `reduced_windows` in Gensim source, & simple `b` in the original `word2vec.c` code) are resampled *per center context word*, not per 'sentence' (text) or batch.